# Yndefined reference to function

Tags: c, string, pointers, struct

When I build the code below, I get an error stating the following (on main functions A and B):

> undefined reference to 'new_string(char const*)'

I'm not sure what's wrong, or how to fix it.

**string.h (header)**

```
typedef struct tag_string {
    char *str;      
    unsigned int len;   

    int (*compare)(struct tag_string *target);  
    struct tag_string *(*set)(struct tag_string *target);

} string;

string *new_string(const char *str);
void delete_string(string *str);

int string_compare(string *target);
string *string_set(string *target);
```

**Other source file**

```
#include "string.h"
#include <stdlib.h>

extern string *call;

string *new_string(char *str){
string *ptr = 0;

int n = 0;

ptr = (string *)malloc(sizeof(string));

ptr->str = 0;
ptr->len = 0;

ptr->compare = string_compare;
ptr->set = string_set;

if(str){
    for(ptr->len = 0; str[ptr->len];ptr->len++);

    ptr-> str = (char *)malloc(ptr->len+1);

    if(ptr->str == 0){
        free(ptr);
        return 0;
    }

    for(int i=0;i<ptr->len+1;i++){
        ptr->str[i] = str[i];
    }   
}else {
    ptr->str = (char *)malloc(1);
    ptr->str[0] = 0;
}

return ptr;
}
```

**Main file**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "string.h"

extern void *call;

int main(void){
    /*A*/ string *mystr = new_string("My str");
    /*B*/ string *strNULL = new_string(0);

}
```

Comment: How do you compile/link the project?

Comment: um.. just using visual studio complier.
maybe automatically linked..

Comment: Well, looks like some linking issue, the sources seem ok

Comment: Either your compiler/linker command or your project setup is wrong (depending on whether you are using the IDE or manually invoking the compiler)

Comment: Are both source files part of the *project*? It's not enough that they are on the disk in the same directory, they also have to be in the project tree inside Visual Studio.

Comment: Rellay? I need  inquire to cloud IDE company XD

Comment: every file in project tree...
I`m using cloud IDE and i think so It has ploblem...
It using visual studio compiler. but something wrong D:

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please [edit] your code to reduce it to a [mcve] of your problem.  Your current code includes much that is peripheral to your problem - a minimal sample normally looks similar to a good unit test: only performing one task, with input values specified for reproducibility.

Comment: Excuse me, but can you explain it in plain language?
I'm not good at english D:
@TobySpeight

Comment: @TobySpeight No, the code is ok for an MCVE I think, the problem is, that his environment is probably the cause for this issue, which is hard to show here (VisualStudio-GUI-crap)

Comment: @Luvid, I'm saying that your example code could surely be made a lot shorter (and still demonstrate your problem).  That makes it easier for people to reproduce the issue, and to quickly see the problem part.  (At least it would if the problem was in the code - other commenters suggest it's caused by your compiler/linker configuration).

Comment: 1) Enable all warnings, 2) Treat warnings as errors, 3) Post all warnings here. But basically, your "other source file" (`string.c`?) probably isn't included in compilation for your selected build settings. So the prototypes and struct from the header get included, but then the linker cannot find the compiled function once all `.c` files are compiled.

Comment: @Ctx: it's not VS-related, you can exclude files from compilation in any GUI, which is what is probably going on.

Comment: @Groo this was not my point; the point was, that it is hard to provide enough details of the environment here to find the problem when it is a _graphical_ environment.

Comment: @Ctx: CLang gives same error: C and C++ are still different languages, and `iostream` belongs to the the C++ standard library not to the C one

Comment: @SergeBallesta I do not understand what you try to express... What are you referring to?

Comment: @Ctx: Sorry Previous comment is stupid. I just meant that the error is (probably) not caused by a missing translation unit but by a C/C++ mix without the magic `extern "C"`. I could reproduce the problem with CLang (after changing the name of `string.h`). See my answer below...

Comment: @SergeBallesta That sounds quite plausible, yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is likely to be a bad C/C++ mix.

The main source is a C++ source because of the `#include <iostream>`. When you include `string.h`, you get a C++ declaration for :

```
string *new_string(const char *str);
```

If the other source file is a C one (plausible because of the `#include <stdlib.h>`) it only defines a C function, which is not the same as a C++ one: to reach the C function from C++ you need:

```
extern "C" string *new_string(const char *str);
```

Just a guess, but changing the include in main should be enough:

```
#include <iostream>
extern "C" {
#include "string.h"
}

extern void *call;

int main(void){
    /*A*/ string *mystr = new_string("My str");
    /*B*/ string *strNULL = new_string(0);

}
```

But you have an inconsistent declaration:

```
string *new_string(const char *str);  // in header file
```

vs.

```
string *new_string(char *str);       // in other source file
```

And using a name of the header from the standard library (`string.h`) that could be used under the hood by other standard include is a **very** bad idea: it broke in my CLang.